# How to find kth largest sublist(by length) from a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a list like this

```
list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 9, 12], [9], [8], [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16], [7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

I need to find the `k-th` largest sublist by length of the list from the above-nested list, a small twist is there:

- If K =2 the answer should be [4,5,6,7] as it comes later in the
  processing
- If K = 1 the answer should be [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] as it comes later
  in the processing

I initially sorted the nested sublist by length, which I think will be useful to find kth largest sublist, as it also preserves the order for list in which they were processed earlier

```
sorted_list = [[9], [8], [1, 9, 12], [1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Not able to identify the correct way to find the kth largest element from here,

returning `sorted_list[-K]` will not work in most of the cases where the last two sublists are of same length.

Don't confuse lists elements with sorting, sorting is done on the basis of the length of sub-lists and order is preserved in sorted_list

Comment: What do you mean by the 'largest sublist' ?

Comment: why not sort it in reverse order and return `k-1`-th? Still not clear why `k=2` should return `[4,5,6,7]`. Maybe just sort on 2-element tuple - len and original index.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12062831/g%c3%b6khan-san https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran by largest sublist means the size of the list in the nested list; similar to the largest number here size of the list will determine the list.

Comment: Also not sure why [4,5,6,7] is the second largest list there. Can you write out what the correct fully sorted list of lists should be for your example?

Comment: Why `k=2` should return `[4,5,6,7]` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran [4,5,6,7] will be the 2nd largest sublist because [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] and [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16] are of the same length. so [4,5,6,7] should be the 2nd largest.

Comment: So according to that `k=1` should be `[7,8,9,10,12,16]`

Comment: So, would it be fair to rephrase your question as 'Of all the distinct lengths of lists, find the list whose length is the kth largest distinct length, and appears last in the original list?'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13890216/lakshika-parihar no because [7,8,9,10,12,16] is processed earlier than [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] in the original list and the same order is preserved in the sorted_list, only the sub-lists are sorted by length.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16757174/kcsquared yes you can phrase it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Python's `itertools.groupby` applied to your sorted list: then accessing index `-k` of the grouped list gives you all lists of the kth largest length, of which you wanted the last one:

```py
import itertools

nums = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 9, 12], [9], [8], [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16], [7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
sorted_list = sorted(nums, key=len)

grouped_list = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_list, len)]

def kth_largest(k: int):
    return grouped_list[-k][-1]

print(kth_largest(k=2))
print(kth_largest(k=1))
```

gives:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to find the unique elements by length and then sort the values to find the corresponding kth element:

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 9, 12], [9], [8], [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16], [7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]

# the dictionary will store the last appearing element of the corresponding key (the later one in the processing)
lookup = {len(e): e for e in lst}

# sort the values of the lookup dictionary, reverse by len
res = sorted(lookup.values(), key=len, reverse=True)

k = 2
print(res[k - 1])

k = 1
print(res[k - 1])
```

**Output**

```
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```